# Jee6 Basic Rest service returns 404

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee

I'm currently switching from Spring Framework to JEE6 and am PoC testing some functionalities. One of them are Rest services. I'm pretty sure that I followed the JEE6 tutorial using rest annotations and also cross-checked the JEE5 sample for rest webservices. However, my example does return a 404 message. A normal @WebServlet controller is running okay, so I don't have any internal/deployment related errors. Log-file/ Stacktrace is also empty.

Would be great if you could give me some advice. Thanks!

J

---

Controller class

```
package guest;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

// The Java class will be hosted at the URI path "/helloworld"
@Stateless
@Path("/helloWorld")
public class GuestRest {

    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    @Path("test")
    @GET
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        // Return some cliched textual content
        return "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";
    }
}
```

---

```
glassfish-web.xml

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/Guestbook</context-root>

</glassfish-web-app>
```

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which path are you making a request against?

Comment: @Blaskovicz: I should have written that down as well. It's
http://localhost:8080/GuestBook/helloWorld/test

Comment: Try Guestbook with lower case book, as this is your context root.

Comment: @Gas: tried this as well: http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/helloWorld/test. but still 404
any additional ideas?

Comment: Remove @Statless from your class. This is not EJB. Check your web.xml. You should have `servlet-mapping` with `url-pattern`, it usually is something like `/rest/*` or `/jaxrs/*`. So your full url should be something like: http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/rest/helloWorld/test. This at least works in WebSphere Liberty. I dont have Gassfish at hand to test.

Comment: Hey Gas thank for your help. Really appreciate it! 
I added my web.xml as well. However - same error when calling http://localhost:8080/Guestbook/rest/helloWorld/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your web.xml like this (3.0 version and different REST initialization):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>JAXRSSample</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: That's totally it! You made my day :) 
Would it be possible to point out the main differences between your web.xml and mine? (appart from the obvious?) Thanks again!

Comment: This is preferred JAXRS 1.1 configuration method. You used the older one for servlet 2.5 containers. And I think looking at it now, you used incorrect classname, probably from older Jersey version (it had changed). Take a look at this link it explains various configuration methods - https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet